# How to access system environment variables in Next.js?

Tags: docker, environment-variables, next.js

I created a Next.JS app which uses environment variables. I have the environment variables needed as the system's environment variables (because it is a dockerized nextjs app).

```sh
# in terminal
echo $NEXT_PUBLIC_KEY_NAME
# >> value of key
```

but `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_KEY_NAME` is undefined in the app only when running in production mode. How can I access them? I can't seem to find any documentation on this on Nextjs's website or anywhere else.

Comment: What is the `CMD` of your Dockerfile? How/What command do you run your app?
If you start your Next.js app as a minimal server (next start, node server.js...) you can set env vars before running command and it would not be undefined.
If you start your Next.js by building & exporting the static files (`next build`, `next export`) and serve them behind a proxy, you have to set env vars before `next build`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### NextJS Solution

NextJS has built in support to accomplish what you want,
you just need to put your environment variables inside `.env.local` in your ***root folder***.

Other than `.env.local`, you can also use `.env`, `.env.development`, and `.env.production`.

an example of `.env.local`:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=myuser
DB_PASS=mypassword
```

in your case, it will become:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_KEY_NAME=[insert_what_you_want]
```

voila, you can access it from your NextJS app, using `process.env.` keyword.

```
// pages/index.js
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const db = await myDB.connect({
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
  })
  // ...
}
```

You can read more from the [source](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables).

---

### Docker Solution

If the above solution is not the one you are looking for, then what you need is how to set env variable on Docker instead of NextJS.

If you are using docker-compose file:

```
frontend:
    image: frontend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - NEXT_PUBLIC_KEY_NAME=[insert_what_you_want]
```

if you run the docker manual, use `-e` parameters:

```
docker run -e NEXT_PUBLIC_KEY_NAME=[insert_what_you_want] frontend bash
```

or using env file on docker command:

```
docker run --env-file ./env.list frontend bash
```

you can read more from the [source](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file).

Comment: do you have an dockerfile for this setup which is working?

Comment: I found this solution for docker file: https://blog.renatopozzi.me/manage-nextpublic-environment-variables-at-runtime-with-docker

Comment: @TuanLECONG link is dead, can you share the solution please? Accepted answer doesn't work, runtime docker environment variables are not accessible in next.js browser.

Comment: @pseudozach This is the article that Tuan shared on dev.to: https://dev.to/itsrennyman/manage-nextpublic-environment-variables-at-runtime-with-docker-53dl